# knp_paginator no funciona en servicio Symfony

Tags: symfony2, symfony, servicio

Tengo definido una funcion en la que empleo el paginador, usado en mis controladores funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, cuando defino un servicio para no copiar y pegar el code, tengo lo siguiente:

```
 app.paginacion:
    class: Caja\SiafcaInternetBundle\Services\Paginacion
    public: true
    arguments: ["@knp_paginator"]
```

En mi config.yml

```
knp_paginator:
page_range: "%knp_paginator_page_range%"
default_options:
    page_name: "%knp_paginator_page_name%"
    sort_field_name: "%knp_paginator_sort_field_name%"
    sort_direction_name: "%knp_paginator_sort_direction_name%"
    distinct: "%knp_paginator_distinct%"
template:
    pagination: "%knp_paginator_pagination%"
    sortable: "%knp_paginator_sortable%"
```

Y en mi controllador defino la siguiente clase

```
class Paginacion{

private $paginator;

public function __contruct($paginator){
   $this->$paginator = $paginator;
} 

public function obtenerPaginacion($request,$aportantesWS,$totalAportantes)
{
    if (!$aportantesWS) 
    {
        $pagination = null;
    } 
    else 
    {
        // $paginator = $this->get('app.knp_paginator');
        $pagination = 
                $this->paginator->paginate(
                                        $aportantesWS,
                                        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
                                        20
                                    );
        $pagination->setTotalItemCount($totalAportantes);
    }
    return $pagination;
}}
```

Por ejemplo llamandolo:

```
$this->get('app.paginacion')->obtenerPaginacion($request,$aportantesWS,$totalAportantes)
```

Cuando intento usarlo, me genera el siguiente error
**Error: Call to a member function paginate() on null**
Revisando con **dump()** los datos de *request*,*aportantesWS* y *totalaportantes* vienen no nulos, es decir con datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la soluciòn. Siguiendo el siguiente [posteo en stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131406/the-right-way-of-using-a-pagination-class-in-symfony)

Modifique mi definiciòn en **services.yml**

```
paginacion:
    class: Caja\SiafcaInternetBundle\Services\Paginacion
    public: true
    arguments: ["@knp_paginator"]
    calls:
    - [setPaginator, ["@knp_paginator"]]
```

Incorpore el *calls -[setPaginator, ["@knp_paginator"]]*

Modifique mi controlador incorporando el metodo *setPaginator*

```
public function setPaginator($paginator)
{
    $this->paginator = $paginator;
}
```

Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
class Paginacion{

private $paginator;

public function __contruct($paginator){
   $this->$paginator = $paginator;
}

public function setPaginator($paginator)
{
    $this->paginator = $paginator;
}

public function obtenerPaginacion($request,$aportantesWS,$totalAportantes)
{
    if (!$aportantesWS) 
    {
        $pagination = null;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $pagination = 
                $this->paginator->paginate(
                                        $aportantesWS,
                                        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
                                        20
                                    );
        $pagination->setTotalItemCount($totalAportantes);
    }
    return $pagination;
}}
```